# can't figure out how to write a simple DB2 function

Tags: sql, db2

It seems simple but I tried hours to figure it out but I can't..

I wish to create a db2 function which works like coalesce.

The difference is it looks for the value of the first parameter, if it is an empty string which is ''. Then It will use the second parameter.

That's the query I did

```
 CREATE FUNCTION COALESCEEMPTY (X1 XML, X2 XML)
 RETURNS XML
 LANGUAGE SQL
 CONTAINS SQL
 NO EXTERNAL ACTION
 DETERMINISTIC
 CASE X1
 WHEN '' THEN RETURN X2;
 ELSE RETURN X1;
 END CASE;
```

and this is the error code i get from db2.

```
16:09:47  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=X1
 WHEN '' THEN RETURN X2;ERMINISTIC
 CASE;<space>, DRIVER=4.13.127
16:09:47  [ELSE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=RETURN;ELSE ;JOIN <joined_table>, DRIVER=4.13.127
16:09:47  [END - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=END-OF-STATEMENT;END CASE;JOIN <joined_table>, DRIVER=4.13.127
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I only do SQL UDFs on Teradata, but DB2 syntax is quite similar.
This should work

```
CREATE FUNCTION COALESCEEMPTY (X1 XML, X2 XML)
RETURNS XML
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN 
   CASE WHEN X1 = '' THEN X2 ELSE X1 END;
```

Comment: thanks.. just tried.       16:30:28  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=CASE;THEN X2 ELSE X1 END;END-OF-STATEMENT, DRIVER=4.13.127

Comment: I just checked DB2 syntax and there's no END CASE just END (copied it from your function), maybe that's the problem.

Comment: not right. but close..18:02:17  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -401, SQL State: 42818]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-401, SQLSTATE=42818, SQLERRMC=WHEN, DRIVER=4.13.127

Comment: Next try :-) Changed to a Searched CASE. Plus, what if you simply write a COALESCE(X1,X2) to see if it fails, too.

Answer (score 0):

Empty string is not a well-formed XML fragment, so it should not be possible for an XML host variable to be an empty string. If you mean to check for a NULL value, as implied by the function name, it should look like

```
CASE WHEN X1 IS NULL THEN X2 ELSE X1 END
```

In standard SQL NULL and empty string are different things.